# Two counts in three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to count two columns using the following query:

```
select distinct [District], 
  count (Distinct [Student Identifier Statewide California]) 
         as '11-12 Enrollment',
  (select count (Distinct IncdtKey) 
From [dbo].[DisciplineStudentFile1112]
where GrdLvLKey in ('15', '01', '02', '03', '04', 
                        '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', 
                        '10', '11', '12', '18', '19')) as Total_Incidents
From 
  dbo.SSID1112StudentEnrollmentRecords with (nolock)
inner join 
  [dbo].[SchoolDetail] on CDSCode = dbo.SSID1112StudentEnrollmentRecords.CDSOrig
where  
  [EnrollStatCodeOrig] like '10'
and 
  [Grade Level Code] in ('PS', 'KN', '01', '02', '03', 
                         '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', 
                         '09', '10', '11', '12', 'UE', 'US')
group by [District]
order by [District]
```

My results are:

```
District      11-12 Enrollment  Total_Incidents
AB Unified          20662                896371
CE Unified          5387                 896371
DR Unified          526                  896371
FJ Unified          1506                 896371
KT Unified          8415                 896371
```

I can't figure out how to get the individual counts in the `Total_Incidents` column instead of a total 896371 count?

Comment: Hi, can you specify the name of your database manager?

Comment: Usually getting individual counts requires a `group by` clause. Have you tried `group by [Total Incidents]`?

Comment: Thanks anakata. It is SQL Server management Studio

Comment: I tried Group by District, Total Incidents but get Invalid Column name error

Comment: Can I use another Group by in the subquery and where to put?

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach is to correlate the subquery with the outer query:

```
select distinct SD.District,
  count ( distinct SER.[Student Identifier Statewide California] ) as [11-12 Enrollment],
  ( select count( distinct DSF.IncdtKey ) from dbo.DisciplineStudentFile1112 as DSF
    where DSF.GrdLvLKey in ( '15', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', 
      '10', '11', '12', '18', '19' ) and -- Note additional condition here.
      DSF.District = SD.District ) as Total_Incidents
from dbo.SSID1112StudentEnrollmentRecords as SER with (nolock) inner join 
  dbo.SchoolDetail as SD on SD.CDSCode = SER.CDSOrig
where SER.EnrollStatCodeOrig like '10' and 
  [Grade Level Code] in ( 'PS', 'KN', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', 
  '09', '10', '11', '12', 'UE', 'US' )
group by SD.District
order by SD.District
```

I have made some assumptions about the table schemas.  I would recommend that when using joins that you supply an alias for each table and use the alias on every reference to avoid confusion.

An alternative solution would be to use another join with `DisciplineStudentFile1112` and then summarize the results using `GROUP BY`.

Comment: HABO Thank you so much. Your solution worked perfectly. And thanks for showing me the correlation steps.